# upgrading from PHP 5.1 to PHP 5.3

Tags: php, migration

I am currently investigating the viability of upgrading my site from PHP 5.1.6 to 5.3.10. The site is running on CentOS.

I am aware of the major differences such as the introduction of namespaces and closures. I've also spent some time going through the "Backward Incompatibility Changes" on the Migration Guides which look good and will be where i'll be spending a considerable amount of time.

Are there any "gotchas" that I should keep an eye out for?

Comment: One thing I would want to say.. If you have most of your codebase properly unittested, this question would be unneeded and you'd be nearly 100% sure things will be just fine.

Comment: @Evert: Not so, many things changed between those versions.  ie. what was correct in v5.1 is not always so in v5.3, so unit testing would not help there at all.

Comment: The main "gotcha" is that PHP 5.4 is now out.

Comment: Well if you'd run all your unittests on 5.3, wouldn't you know (almost) for sure things will work?

Comment: @crmpicco: Make sure any extensions you are using have not disappeared or changed, default install is a little different.  eCommerce sites often use the MHash library, that changed a fair bit in terms of calling - as long as you've been through the [backwards incompatible changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php) like you said, should be OK.  But be prepared for some quick recoding and test things thoroughly.

Comment: @Evert: He has not got v5.3 installed - he is talking about upgrading.  On a live server, it is not easy to have both installed simultaneously as a rule.

Comment: Who runs unittests and tests on a live server?? seriously

Comment: @Evert I have some PHPUnit tests written for at least some of the application, however the coverage is quite small. I will certainly be running the following the upgrade.

Comment: @Xeoncross I am aware of PHP 5.4's recent release, however I am concerned about support and potential issues considering it is so recently released.

Comment: @crmpicco I also think it's wise to wait for at least 5.4.1. Historically the x.x.0 releases have almost always had some issues.

Comment: @Orbling Coincidentally, I am updating the code on an eCommerce site, however I am not using the MHash library - http://php.net/manual/en/book.mhash.php

Comment: @Evert I feel that 5.1.6 -> 5.4.x is quite a big jump so i'm thinking I will do it in two stages; 5.1.6 -> 5.3.10 and then onto 5.4.x.

Comment: @Evert You still have to test a live server, you can not assume what works on a dev environment will definitely be identical on a different environment.

Comment: If you upgrade to 5.4.0, you are asking for trouble. You should wait until 5.4.1 + 3 weeks before rolling out to production machines. Going to 5.3.10 then to 5.4 is a better rollout strategy imo.

Comment: @MikePurcell Thanks, that is exactly what I am going to do. My upgrade is going from 5.1.6 to 5.3.10.

Comment: Sounds like you got it handled. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently made the jump to 5.3.x as well and noted the following issues (sourced from my [blog](http://melikedev.com/2010/10/07/php-upgrade-to-5-3-x-things-to-look-out-for/)):

**date.timezone (php.ini):**

- PHP developers decreased the error level from strict to warning, so you will see numerous warnings around any date functions if you do not have this set correctly.

Example:

```
date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles
```

**__toString():**

- In PHP 5.3, the magic __toString() methods no longer allow you to pass in arguments, which makes sense on some level, but does reduce flexibility.

As mentioned in the comments, you are better off upgrading to 5.3.10, then migrating to 5.4.1 or even 5.4.2. Immediately jumping to 5.4.0 is not a good idea, and you will see why when they post the changelog for 5.4.1.

Comment: Aside from some changes like this, making sure you install the extensions you took for granted in your last install is half the battle, writing code correctly will solve the other half.

Answer (score 1):

I had to get a MediaWiki 1.15.1 working on PHP 5.3 because I was rehosting it [(here)](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Main_Page).  The then dev team had been "let go" in the hand-over, so it the community volunteers needed to step in to do this. The MW developers advice was "MW1.15 is not compatible with PHP 5.3; upgrade to MW 1.17"

For various reasons related to custom extensions and the need to stick with MW 1.15 schema as a stepping stone, I had to stick with MW 1.15.  Man, was it a pain!!!!

The main issue was the "The behaviour of functions with by-reference parameters called by value has changed. Where previously the function would accept the by-value argument, a fatal error is now emitted."  In other words 5.1 and 5.2 had a sloppy toleration here and 5.3 would barf with a fatal error.  Finding all of these statically was just impractical so it was a case of trying to exercise of common paths, mining the error logs to drill down and find the dozens of cases where this happened and check against the documented APIs to fix each on a case by case basis.  I can't think of any of the other [incompatibilities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php) that burnt.